# Determine iPhone Screen Tapped is in region or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I want to determine whether the tapped location is in region or not. I have 4 CGPoints and I know this can be done by using UITouch. Also, I have screen tapped location by using the function

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex: 0];
    CGPoint currentPos = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
}
```

And for example my 4 CGPoints are

```
self.firstPoint = CGPointMake(50.0f, 50.0f);
self.secondPoint = CGPointMake(200.0, 50.0);
self.thirdPoint = CGPointMake(200.0, 200.0);
self.fourthPoint = CGPointMake(50.0, 120.0);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @H2CO3 unless that last point is a typo, that's not a rectangle.

Comment: @H2CO3 as his region is not a Rectangle he should build a CGPath and use `CGPathContainsPoint`, or correct his question so his points make up a Rectangle.

Comment: @Kevin and Jonathan: right.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `CGRect` to represent the rect instead of four `CGPoint`s and then use `CGRectContainsPoint()` to check if the rect contains the point.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
     CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.gif"];
    newView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    if (location.y<480|| location.y>50)
    {
        //write your code

    }


}
```